# Designing a mechanism for moving a tank in circular motion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

Thanks everyone. For a university proyect of fluid mechanics we have designed a device that rotates a tank separating the movements for both axis in the horizontal and vertical one using leadscrews.One moves the horizontal platform and another the vertical platform accelerating sinusoidally both the platforms to control the movement. As you can see the work is high on the vertical axis. So will it make sense to use a counterweight on the z axis?. Any suggestions? The radius will be small from 2 cm to 10 cm. Mass of the tank is rather high +20kg.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the blue component? ... what are the dark green components? ... what are the other components?